# Cypress cannot find the browser when ran from module api

Tags: node.js, cypress

I'm trying to run a pretty simple test through cypress , with [chrome](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers#Customize-available-browsers) , through [module-api](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api). I don't want to run the tests through their launcher but from node as I'll start the tests through mocha framework.
The tests at least can start with electron , but can't find the elements I'm trying to click. It works with chrome through the launcher - with `npx cypress run --browser chrome`. Though when I use the module-api I get this error:

```
Can't run because you've entered an invalid browser name.

Browser: electron was not found on your system or is not supported by Cypress.

Cypress supports the following browsers:
```

Here's my config:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  fixturesFolder: false,
  e2e: {
      experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true, // multi-domain tests as there could be an Auth0 authentication
      setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return {
        browsers: config.browsers.filter(
          (b) => {
              if (b.name == 'chrome') {
                  console.log(b); // print info about the browser
                  return b;
              }
            }
        ),
      }
    }
  },
})
```

The file that starts the test (e.g. `example-test.js`):

```
const cypress = require('cypress')

return cypress.run({
  spec: './cypress/e2e/simple-login.cy.js'
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    process.exit(0);
})
```

I'm starting it with:

```
node example-test.js
```

(the simple-login just enters a password , email and clicks a button and it works when I use `cypress run ..`).

The console log prints correctly the information about the browser ,though still there's an error. Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: Why are you doing that in the configuration? It seems like a ***really*** bad thing to do.

Comment: @SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR - so how I can run a tests through chrome with the module-api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return value in `setupNodeEvents()` is only returning `chrome` type browsers, so the error

> Browser: **electron** was not found on your system or is not supported by Cypress

is caused by that.

The other side-effect is that other config like `experimentalSessionAndOrigin` are being removed.

This is how you can log chrome browsers without changing the config

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  fixturesFolder: false,
  e2e: {
    experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true, 
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.browsers.forEach((b) => {
        if (b.name == 'chrome') {
          console.log(b); // print info about the browser
        }
      })
      return config    // NOTE unchanged config
    }
  },
})
```

---

**Note** `npx cypress run --browser chrome` will work because your filter is allowing chrome browsers to pass, but `npx cypress run --browser electron` will fail.

Comment: thanks. Though in this way it still runs the test with electron. I'm trying also with `setupNodeEvents(on, config) {return {browsers: config.browsers.filter((b) => b.name === 'chrome'),}}` but the error is the same.

Comment: I explained above why that error is happening. There is not any good reason why you need to do that.

Comment: so it won't be possible to run the tests with chrome with such a setup

Comment: You can use chrome as long as it's installed. Don't filter the config, instead specify the browser in the module API parameters - see [example here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api#cypress-run)